# Homogenous Recurrence with Quadratic Coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations, recursion

I wonder if there is a general method for studying second-order homogeneous recurrence relations with quadratic coefficients. I'm considering the following:

$$S_k = a S_{k-1} - (b-k) (k-1) S_{k-2}$$

with $S_0 = 1$ and $S_1 =a$.

Comment: is really $$S_2=a$$?

Comment: I apologize. It's $S_1 = a$. The recurrence relation is valid for $k\geq2$.

Answer (score 2):

Generating functions are a pretty good bet. Define $F(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty S_k x^k$. Now take your equation above and multiply both sides by $x^k$ getting

$$S_k x^k = a S_{k-1}x^k - (k^2  - (b+1)k + b) S_{k-2}x^k.$$

Next sum from $k=2$ to infinity to get

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \left( S_k x^k \right) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \left( a S_{k-1}x^k\right) - \sum_{k=2}^\infty \left( (k^2  - (b+1)k + b) S_{k-2}x^k\right).$$

The LHS is just $F(x) -ax-1$, and we can start messing around with the right hand side to get it in terms of $F(x)$ and it's derivatives. Eventually we'll get a second order differential equation. Solving that differential equation and examining the Maclaurin series of the solutions gets us a simplified expression for $S_k$.

Comment: Solved for the generating function like you said, but the solution is a real monster. I wonder if I can somehow simplify the recurrence relation sing the fact that $a$ and $b$ are both very large numbers.

Comment: Indeed, I just worked out the differential equation and it doesn't look pretty. It's close to being an Euler equation, but not quite, and close to being homogeneous, but not quite. You may want to try finding an asymptotic solution to the differential equation instead.